# Icon wont appear when I am styling the span element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to inserting an image which is the & symbol but it wont seem to be appearing within my html.

My HTML code is :

```
  <section style= "background: #FEFEFE;" id="intro">
  <b>" We are a digital marketing shop that creates marketing solutions" <br>
  <br>


   As designers, programmers <span> & </span> problem solvers, we love all things                          

  </b>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
 #intro {
     height: auto;
     padding: 50px 0;
     background: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     color: #52626e;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-weight: normal;
 }
 #intro span {
     background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat -0px -13px;
     padding: 0 12px;
     text-indent: -9999em;
     display: inline-block;
     *display:inline;
 }
```

Comment: a bare `&` in HTML is wrong. It should be `&amp;`.

Comment: @Austin you dont need an img tag if your using a CSS background image

Comment: why do you have the & inside the span if you are going to render a background image

Comment: Verify that `icons.png` exists one directory up, and then in an images folder.    A lot of times I like just going right from root with / instead of relying on ../   (which means up one dir, then back down into another dir of images).     Lastly, try wrapping it in a temp border style or give it specific widths to see if it's putting your background in a spot you're not expecting.

Comment: Do you want me to put the img src within the span tag thats where i want the image. The image is inside an img folder and is called icon.jpg

Comment: Your image path (or positioning) seems to be incorrect, as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s922dzgp/1/) works. Check to see if the image is being loaded.

Comment: Also, don't use `<br>` for spacing. Use proper elements with padding & margins.

Answer (score 3):

```
#intro {
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #52626e;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#intro span {
  background: url(http://www.makeyourowngarments.com/sites/default/files/our_images/&%20sign.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

take a look at the quick and dirty example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackbiron/xe2rn33a/)

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: i don't have explanation for that, on which point you have problem to understand with?

Comment: It is not immediately clear what you have changed from the original code to solve the problem.

Comment: the point is...the original code is almost there, but seems he copying it from somewhere, and it's contain background position. see `-0px -13px` on this line `background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat -0px -13px;`. it caused the image not appear, unless he use sprite image (i'm pretty sure he don't)